# Properly saving non standard symbols to db

Tags: php, encoding

Sometimes when you have to copy-paste data from somewhere and paste it and store in your db some non-standard symbols also get copied and they break the page. I know using htmlspecialchars, htmlentities etc functions properly encode html symbols like /, ', ", - etc but when I am trying to copy a content and paste it in my textbox to save it some characters are not recognized and nothing gets saved. Those characters look like hyphen, double and single quotes but they are not standard ones. For example, in (Kids – Application form) text the dash is not actually hyphen or double hyphen. Similarly, in (...callipers mounted disc brakes on each wheel with two TMC’s.) is not single quote but look like it. I have applied all proper PHP functions but these unrecognized characters are not saving in db. So how to deal with these and potentially other such symbols?

Comment: Use *placeholders* when saving (prevents all SQL Injection). Use *escaping* when using (prevents all HTML Injection). Make sure to enable/utilize UTF[-8] encoding as appropriate if there is Unicode in play.

Comment: That sounds more like a typical problem with character encoding.

Answer (score 0):

The answer for my question is I did not add utf-8 encoding to my pages and also MYSQL db needs to be saved to utf8_general_ci from deault latin_swedish_ci and use of mysqli_real_escape_string() function save the data properly.